# how to open a page and scroll to a specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

On my Wordpress site I have a link that target a specific page in a different domain.
I need to open that page and directly scroll to a specific div (identified by its class). That div doesn't have an anchor and I have no control on its code so I cannot add it. 
On the target site you can scroll to that div by clicking a button that triggers the following js code:

```
$(".call-action").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".tuoViaggio").offset().top-$("header").height()
        }, 2000);
    });
```

What are my options to directly move to the div with class tuoViaggio by leveraging only the href on my domain?

Comment: If they do not have anchors and it is a different domain, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: You can try adding id to the section of domain that you want to redirect to. Then you can just append like www.example.com/#my-custom-id

Comment: you are referring to adding an anchor, not an ID. And if you read my post, I have no access to the destination domain @paudel

Comment: To be fair to @paudel, you can use the `id` of an element (not sure if it's any element, but definitely `<div>`).  For instance, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042573/how-to-open-a-page-and-scroll-to-a-specific-position#answers) to get straight to the `<div id="answers">` section of this question. So if there's a specific element with an `id` you can use (instead of the `class`) in the destination, that could be a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. That's [XSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross-site_scripting) (cross-site scripting)